# Use macros from different project in the same Visual Studio C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macros

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and have multiple C# projects in my solution. I want to add a post-build script to project A but I need some of the macros (for example OutputDir) of project B in the solution. Is there any way to do this? When I google I only find infos about c++ property pages or something along those lines. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried with

```
echo "PROJECTNAME-($OutputDir)"
```

but of course it didn't work.

Example of what I want:

```
echo $(OutputDir) // print the output dir of THIS project
echo "ProjectB-$(OutputDir)" // print the output dir of PROJECT B which is in the same solution
```

Comment: So, do you want a solution-level build event, or do you want the macros to be usable in project A but when expanded take the values from project B?

Comment: Basically I want to be able to get the value of Project Bs macros in Project A while still being able to get project As macros. 

basic example: when I build project A it should echo the OutputDir of project A and project B